# Post form from modal partial view to a different controller with a routeprefix attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, html.beginform

I have a partial view that has a form - I launch this partial from the Home controller.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CloudContent","Files", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div id="container"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="PostMe" title="Submit" value="Submit Form" /> 
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyProperty);
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedIds);
}
```

I want to post this form to the Files controller, however the files controller has a route prefix:
`[RoutePrefix("sth/api/v1/files")]`

Which results in my form action being empty.

It doesn't seem to be added to named routes, so I cannot use the beginrouteform. Also, I have little influence over the application, so it's best handled in my form or partial view...

The method that I want to post to in the files controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("getcloudcontent")]
public List<ConnectedFile> CloudContent(CloudFilesModel model)
{
    //do magic
}
```

Comment: Instead of using the html helper you can write the html yourself.  Helpers are great if it is exactly what you want but can be a pain if you deviate at all from exactly what they do.  Another option would be to write a custom helper.  If this is a 1-off then it isn't worth it though.

Comment: Other options would include writing your own route in the RouteConfig.cs (ick) or adding a route attribute to the method in the Files controller.  If you don't have access to those though then writing the form route explicitly is your best bet.

Comment: @nurdyguy - I can add a route attribute to the method in Files controller - I actually have one `[Route("getcloudcontent")]`, but I suppose the prefix still matters?

Comment: `[Route("Files/CloudContent")]` Doesn't that work?

Comment: @nurdyguy - is that attribute supposed to overwrite the routeprefix attribute specified on the Controller class?

Comment: No.  The route attribute just tells MVC that you want that path to route into that function.  You can even have multiple route attributes on the same function if you want.

Comment: @nurdguy So if I specify `[Route("Files/CloudContent")]` for my method and still have the `[RoutePrefix("sth/api/v1/files")]`, then the method will be accessible via /sth/api/v1/files/Files/CloudContent, right?

Comment: From the documentation I read it sounded like it would work.  However, when I tried it on a test project it did not.  The RoutePrefix will prepend the Route attribute which means this probably won't work for you.  For your situation I think writing the form explicitly is probably best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Here is another example which includes partial view / child action:

**HomeController.cs:**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("~/")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("ModalContent")]
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult ModalContent()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**FilesController.cs:**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

[RoutePrefix("sth/api/v1/files")]
public class FilesController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("getcloudcontent")]
    public ActionResult CloudContent(string model)
    {
        return Content("test");
    }
}
```

**Views\Home\Index.cshtml:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Show modal
    </button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @Html.Action("ModalContent")
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Views\Home\ModalContent.cshtml:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CloudContent", "Files", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div id="container"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="PostMe" title="Submit" value="Submit Form" />
}
```

**Global.asax.cs:**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

And the result HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Show modal
    </button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="/sth/api/v1/files/getcloudcontent" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                        <div id="container"></div>
                        <input type="submit" name="PostMe" title="Submit" value="Submit Form" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

There is something different that is wrong with your code. I ran your code and it worked without any issues.

Here is the code:

**FilesController.cs:**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("sth/api/v1/files")]
    public class FilesController : Controller
    {
        [Route("")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("getcloudcontent")]
        public ActionResult CloudContent(string model)
        {
            return Content("test");
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CloudContent", "Files", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div id="container"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="PostMe" title="Submit" value="Submit Form" />
}
```

**Global.asax.cs:**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

When I go to http://localhost/sth/api/v1/files I see the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
    <form action="/sth/api/v1/files/getcloudcontent" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">    <div id="container"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="PostMe" title="Submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice that form action has the correct URL which includes prefix.

Comment: Tested with partial view. Works as well.

Comment: Thanks - could it be a matter of my PartialView being returned from some Home controller action and displayed as a bootstrap modal?

Comment: It shouldn't, since partials are rendered on the server side as a result of the `@Html.Partial(partialViewName)` call, so they "don't know" where are they getting rendered in. But based on your comment of "partial view being returned from controller action" I think you meant child action, which is slightly different case. Let me update my answer with another example.